# call method inside a class

Tags: java, multithreading, methods

Greetings

I'm developing my first app in java and I wanted to know how can I do the following

I created this

```
public class Test
{
     ...

     public void control()
     {
          final ArrayList<Module> mods = new ArrayList<Module>();
          if (i == 0)
          {
               mods.add( null );
               mods.add(moduleList.get( i ));
               Thread t = new Thread( new Runnable()
               {
                    public void run()
                    {
                         StartController(mods);
                    }             
               });     
          }
     }

     public void StartController(ArrayList<Module> modList)
     {
          //Do Stuff
     }
}
```

But I am unable to accomplish this! he can't find StartController....

I would like to keep the code close to this. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Actually, as shown, this should work just fine. Your actual code must be different from this in some way.

Comment: it is a good practice to begin the mentods name in lowercase. In multi-word names, the first letter of each of the second and following words should be capitalized. i.e public void startController(ArrayList<Module> modList) more info [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

Comment: hum... Ernest I believe you are right, probably was the IDE that was buggy.... it's working!

Answer (score 1):

That looks 100% correct but a common solution for this, in situtations where that type of call doesn't work, is to do:

```
Test.this.StartController(mods)
```

instead of

```
StartController(mods)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use ExecutorService and the Runnable interface instead. You can see an easy example right here:

http://programmingexamples.wikidot.com/executorservice

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to make the StartController(..) method static.

```
public static void StartController(ArrayList<Module> mods) {
  // do stuff
}
```

And then change the call to:

```
Test.StartController(mods);
```